# Is the set null($A$)={$x \in R^3 :Ax=0$} a subspace of $R^3$? Show by applying the subspace theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a fixed matrix $A \in M_{3×3}$. Show that the set null($A$)={$x \in R^3 :Ax=0$}
is a subspace of $R^3$ by applying the subspace theorem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by subspace theorem.

Given $x,y \in null(A)$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$,  $A(\alpha x + y) = \alpha A(x) + A(y) = 0 + 0 = 0$.

Therefore $null(A)$ is closed by sum and scalar multiplication, thus, is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.